# Ms Teams HelloWorld Sample: Emulator not working: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have the HelloWorld app sample running (browser launches: http://localhost:3333/)

In Bot Framework Emulator, I open a Bot (http://localhost:3333/api/messages) and connect.

I write a message and I see:

```
Cannot post activity. Unauthorized.
POST 401 directline.postActivity
```

I have tried with and without ngrok, but I suppose that is not the problem.

What can be wrong?

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: Could you please check AppSettings in web.config file? And  make sure you have correctly provided key-value under AppSettings in web.config file.

Comment: In Web.config - appSettings I have MicrosoftAppId = [Project Properties-Application-Assembly-GUI value] and MicrosoftAppPassword =""

Comment: Could you please share your bot id?

Comment: I.m afraid this is the problem... I thought that to test my web app locally it was enough to have the project running in Visual Studio and emulator could communicate with it. I have not managed any bot id here... I have a bot created in https://dev.botframework.com since I tried to load my app to Teams application (with no success), what must I do in this local case? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You can see the bot id under bot settings at [dev.botframework.com](https://dev.botframework.com), Please update your app settings with created bot id and bot password within web.config file also update the your manifest with the same bot id. Please try this and let us know if you face any issue.

Comment: I used the Id from the field 'Paste your app ID below to continue' (dev.botframework.com) in Web.config (appSettings-MicrosoftAppId) and in manifiest.json (3 times: 'botId' in 'bots' and in 'composeExtensions', 'id' in top value). Value: 65d82fa2-e868-4ed1-808b-8f9c2a6cb2e1
Bot password for Web.config (appSettings-MicrosoftAppPassword) I can not find the valud in dev.botframework.com... I used the 'Secret Key' (there are 2 values) in 'Web Chat' tab (quite long value)

But with that Ids I still get the 401 in the emulator...

Comment: I also tried with the GUID value (application project 'Assembly Info') for the manifest.json 'id' (top value). But no success

Comment: Please update the message endpoint to ngrok url  "https://yourteamsapp.ngrok.io/api/message" and give a try.

Comment: I have it running in the emulator (with http://localhost:3333/api/messages or https://d158abf1.ngrok.io/...) but only if I leave empty 'MicrosoftAppId' and 'MicrosoftAppPassword' values in 'Web.config' project file... Why is that? I mean I have to change these values to load my app to TEAMS client, correct? In this case I can not use the emulator anymore?

Comment: Bot security is configured by the Microsoft App ID and Microsoft App Password that you obtain when you register your bot with the Bot Framework. These values are typically specified within the bot's configuration file and used to retrieve access tokens from the Microsoft Account service. You can test your bot on localhost too please take a look at [Test your bot on localhost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#test-your-bot-on-localhost).

Comment: Could you help me with MicrosoftAppPassword? Where can I found this value in my bot (Bot Framework)? Is it the 'Secret Key' (there are 2 values) in 'Web Chat' tab (quite long value)? Thanks

Comment: You can find the Microsoft App Password for your bot inside certificates and secrets in [portal.azure.com](https://ms.portal.azure.com) where your bot is registered or you follow up with [Get started on the Microsoft Teams platform with C#/.NET and App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio) for creating a Teams application with bot.

Comment: I have my bot in https://dev.botframework.com/bots (My bots), but in Settings I can not see any password. And there is no certificate there...

Comment: You can manage Microsoft App ID and App Password it will redirect you to azure portal where you can see the certificates and secrets option.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I have set in my EchoBot Visual project (appsettings.json) 'MicrosoftAppId' & 'MicrosoftAppPassword' values (from my registered bot). I have the bot running locally with ngrok. I try the bot in Test panel (https://dev.botframework.com), and it does not work, BUT I see in local ngrok console that the request is received locally: 500 Server Internal Error...

Comment: Did you updated your ngrok messaging end point URL in bot settings?

Comment: yes, I set in https://dev.botframework.com what I see in local console window: https://3915c929.ngrok.io/api/messages. In fact, I see a trace in this local window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199253/discussion-between-diego-and-trinetra-msft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Once I saw that Emulator requires empty 'Appid' and 'PasswordId' values (appsettings.json), I tried to get my BOT running in Teams client.

Now I have my application running locally and a Bot created in Teams client which can interact with it using a ngrok redirection

The key was to create the bot from Team client (not in dev.botframework.com/bots) logged with the same user than in Azure portal, and using App Studio. 
Then an app is automatically created in Azure portal (NewApp).

Important:

- App Id in appsettings.json is the one created from App Studio Bots option. It is also in Azure portal: App registrations-NewApp-'Application (client) ID'. And also twice in botframework (NewBot Settings: 'Bot handle' and 'Configuration'-'Paste your appId below...')
- In App Studio 'app creation' there is another 'App ID' in App Details. It is not required to be the same.
- App password in appsettings.json is the one created in App Studio (App Password -> Generate). It is also in in Azure portal: App registrations-NewApp-Certificates&secrets/Client secrets
- ngrok url must be added in App Studio bot (Messaging endpoint: 'https://xxxxxx.ngrok.io'). It is also in botframework (NewBot Settings-Messaging endpoint)